# load image automtacily to html page withe javascript(not php)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to build a gallery in HTML and load images from a local directory.
I can't use PHP, only JavaScript, HTML, and CSS.

This is my code so far, but it is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dir = "G:\\Arml\\Automation\\System\\Pic\\test\\"; // folder location
  var fileextension = ".jpg"; // image format
  var i = "1";
  $(function imageloop() {
    $("<img />").attr('src', dir + i + fileextension).appendTo(".testing");
    if (i == 10) {
      alert('loaded');
    } else {
      i++;
      imageloop();
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: if you're loading this page via an http:// url, you can't use local `file:///` urls. mixed content like that is not permitted for security reasons.

Comment: you have a `;` after your if else statement which is unnecessary

Comment: Why don't you just set divs to have background-image of the picture instead of trying to make img tags?

Comment: Marc B so what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

1-Could you try to change the variable dir by another name witch could be used by another javascript library

2- give the img width and height like this for example:

```
$("<img width='100' height='50' />").attr('src', dir + i + fileextension ).appendTo(".testing");
```

Comment: I did not understand the first

Comment: try to change :
var dir = "G:\\Arml\\Automation\\System\\Pic\\test\\"; // folder location
by var urlLibImage= "G:\\Arml\\Automation\\System\\Pic\\test\\"; for example.
because the variable dir could be used by any other javascript library used in your app

Answer (score 0):

this is the javaScript was work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var dir = "path"; // folder location
        var fileextension = ".jpg"; // image format
        var i = "1";
        $(function imageloop(){
            $('.gallary').prepend('<li><a href="#"><img id="' + i + '" alt="description" /><img id="1' + i + '" alt="description" class="preview" /></a></li>')
                if (i==11){

                }
                else{
                $("#"+i).attr('src', dir + i + fileextension );
                $("#1"+i).attr('src', dir + i + fileextension );
                i++;
                    imageloop();
                };
        });   
    });
```